How can I share my wireless connection via my ethernet interface on Ubuntu Server 24.10 on Raspberry Pi 4B?
I've tried several different methods to get this working and have come up empty handed with solutions. Each method I have attempted has resulted in the connected machine unable to obtain an IP address. Those methods all used dnsmasq and iptables to create a DHCP server (not necessary, I'd prefer to keep a static IP) and forward traffic over the interface.
Currently, I've got this working using Ubuntu Desktop 24.10 by using the Network Manager GUI in Settings. However, this is only the first job of the RPi out of several server tasks that are planned for it, and I'd like to avoid needing to use Ubuntu Desktop if possible because of the graphical overhead as well as the added security benefits of Ubuntu Server.
Some key points:

The machine is a Raspberry Pi 4B (8GB RAM).
The preferred Ubuntu version is Ubuntu Server 24.10.
The machine will connect to my wireless network while providing a wired connection via its ethernet port to another machine that does not have wireless capability.
The solution should be simple and not overcomplicated, as this is something I'll need to maintain regularly and I don't want a whole lot of overhead here to keep this running smoothly.
I'd like to possibly keep the connected machine under the same subnet/VLAN as the Pi (the Pi has a static local IP of 192.168.1.200), though this is is not entirely necessary, especially if there are security benefits to having the connected machine in its own subnet, behind the Pi. I will, however, still need to be able to forward traffic to the connected machine, as it will host several web and file servers eventually.
The Pi and the connected machine will be hosting web services for myself, so security is a MUST. Any hardening tips are greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance! I know I'm probably missing something simple.

This may not be possible. See this discussion: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=356968

Thanks for the link, that does help somewhat. Starting to think I may be trying to do something impossible or at least impractical for my current situation. I may move towards using the main server machine like it is set up now (i.e. on the Pi's subnet). I can see my other devices on my LAN from the subnet, but cannot see the server from rest of the LAN. Problems to solve would then be: how do I set it up like this using Ubuntu Server on the Pi, and then where can I go to learn about port forwarding from the Pi to its subnet devices and managing a firewall there.
